# Mounting with Nautilus works but fstab gives "Host is down" error?

Tags: nautilus, vpn, fstab, smb

I'm connecting to my university's VPN so I can connect to the network drive. The VPN seems to be working fine and I can connect to the drive by typing the address into Nautilus and entering my login details:

```
smb://139.___.___.140/home
```

However, this fstab entry doesn't work:

```
//139.___.___.140/home /media/___ cifs domain=CS,username==___,password=___,uid=sai,gid=sai  0 0
```

Nor does manually mounting it:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //139.___.___.140/home /media/___ -o domain=CS,username=___,password=___,uid=sai,gid=sai,user
```

The only error it gives is:

```
mount error(112): Host is down
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

It's obvious the host isn't down since I can view the share from Nautilus.

**Why is Nautilus mounting it fine but not the normal mount command? What could cause this error?**

Answer (score 0):

`fstab` is run at boot, before VPN connections get a chance to actually connect.

Run `nmcli con list` to get your connection's UUID. Note that or copy it to a text file.

Now, make another shell script in your home folder:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 25
nmcli up uuid <your uuid here>
sleep 5
mount //139.___.___.140/home /media/___
```

replacing `VPNNAME` with the name of your VPN, and `<your uuid here>` with the UUID you noted earlier when getting the list of network connections.

Add that script to startup applications.

Replace the line in `fstab` with:

```
//139.___.___.140/home /media/___ cifs domain=CS,username==___,password=___,uid=sai,gid=sai,user  0 0
```

so it can be mounted by user.

You'll notice that you need to fill in the data you redacted from your post. The command will take 30 seconds to get intalized, allowing for connectivity. You can make the `sleep` times shorter if you wish.

Comment: While the VPN isn't available at boot time I don't think this is the problem I am currently facing. If I manually start the VPN then run the mount command it gives the same error message.

Comment: @Annan Honestly I don;t know why this would be, but I'll leave my answer up for reference.

Answer (score 0):

This thread http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/mount-drive-on-windows-98-computer-947748/ led me to try several different things.

I ended up specifying the server name (servern=) and capitalizing everything.  That thread mentions using 'sec=lanman' but my problem was with a Windows 7 machine so my final solution was like this:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=___,password=___,servern=NBCLIENTNAME //NBCLIENTNAME/SHARENAME /tmp/mnt
```

I think it was the capitalization that did it.  Not sure if you can get the NetBios names of your remote client or not.  HTH.